# Dropping list of Indexes with pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a list of strings (pandas series) and a pandas data frame. I want to drop the indexes (and their rows) of the data frame if the index exist in the list. How do I do that in pandas without looping over the data frame and without using .drop('xxx') for every element of the list?

Answer (score 5):

```
In [188]: df
Out[188]:
    a   b    c
aa  x  ww  0.5
bb  y  tt  0.7
cc  z  bb  0.9
dd  z  ww  0.6
ee  z  nn  0.1
ff  x  uu  0.3

In [189]: to_drop
Out[189]:
0    bb
1    dd
dtype: object

In [190]: df = df.drop(to_drop)

In [191]: df
Out[191]:
    a   b    c
aa  x  ww  0.5
cc  z  bb  0.9
ee  z  nn  0.1
ff  x  uu  0.3
```

alternatively we can use `query` method:

```
In [196]: df = df.query("index not in @to_drop")

In [197]: df
Out[197]:
    a   b    c
aa  x  ww  0.5
cc  z  bb  0.9
ee  z  nn  0.1
ff  x  uu  0.3
```

Answer (score 4):

Try a boolean mask:

```
df[~df.index.isin(s)]
```